# Android - Canvas Screen Size Relative Drawing

Tags: android, canvas

So everywhere I looked everybody said "multiply your dimensions by `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`. Let me make something clear : **I am not trying to draw a bitmap image.** Rather a stroked circle.

```
Paint.setStrokeWidth(20 * scale);
```

The stroke thickness still looks different on my G3 ( 5.5" 1440x2560 ) and my friend's 5" 1080x1920.

I'm also trying to draw some text and also multiplying the font size with the `scale`. Why is it looking SO different? ( Stroke is WAY thinner on friends phone and text is WAY smaller ).

EDIT: my `scale` is `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`

Thanks a lot for your time

Anyone..?

Comment: Once Im on Linux again, I can tell you what to replace "scale" with, but thats gonna be tomorrow most liikely..

Comment: I did not reboot to Linux now, but take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels - Once you got the dimens, you can code two functions, that will return you a pixel size, once you enter a percentage..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `TypedValue.applyDimension`.

For the stroke width unit i used `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP`, and for the text size i used `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`.